# No puedo instalar oracledb en nodeJs 7 - w7 x64

Tags: nodejs, oracle, npm

Ejecuto el comando:

```
npm install oracle/node-oracledb.git#v2.1.2
```

**link: [Pagina oficial de node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#quickstart)**

Y recibo los siguientes mensajes:

```
> oracledb@2.1.2 install C:\Users\sti\Documents\Softten\qusar-prueba-backup\node_modules\oracledb
    > node-gyp rebuild


    C:\Users\sti\Documents\Softten\qusar-prueba-backup\node_modules\oracledb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\sti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\sti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
    Los proyectos de esta solución se van a compilar de uno en uno. Para habilitar la compilación en paralelo, agregue el modificador "/m".
    C:\Users\sti\Documents\Softten\qusar-prueba-backup\node_modules\oracledb\build\oracledb.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: No se encuentra el proyecto importado "C:
    \Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props". Asegúrese de que la ruta de acceso de la declaración <Import> es correcta y
    de que el archivo se encuentra en el disco.
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\sti\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\sti\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\sti\Documents\Softten\qusar-prueba-backup\node_modules\oracledb
    gyp ERR! node -v v7.4.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! oracledb@2.1.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@2.1.2 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\sti\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-09T19_10_51_357Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Te esta fallando porque no encuentra la ruta donde esta el binario, esta ruta: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/releases/download/v2.1.2/oracledb-v2.1.2-node-v51-win32-x64.gz no existe ingresala manualmente en el navegador y te dará un error 404.

Comment: Gracias mario ahora probe con otro comando oficial, voy a actualizar la pregunta